# Trying to follow a flat feed, getting NotAllowed 403 error from backend with stream.connect(ApiKey, ApiSecret, AppId)

Tags: getstream-io

Getting a forbidden error (403) when trying to follow a feed that exists in Stream. It is weird because I can add activities to feeds no problem with the exact same credentials. Using NodeJs package.